# Performance improvement Entity Framework Core operations on dbset

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a little app with a new's feed (big volumes), and these feed can be seen or not depending of your rôles/functions.

I have some filters to do (if you're in this role, so you can have access to your company feed, or if you're in this role, you must see only this type of news etc...)

It's working, but slowing down with volume.

My question is :

There's a difference between 
- take the dbSet(_context.AdditionnalInformations), join with needed tables, save this into a list (.ToList()) and make operations(filters) on this list ?
OR
- take the dbSet, and add predicate on this expression ?

I think the second option will make operations (rights calculation) on SQL ?

Thank you

Comment: Second approach (SQL) is preferred. But make sure it does not cause [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation) which will have effect similar to the first approach. Which one are you using currently and causing you performance issues?

Comment: Actually doing _context.....ToList().AsQueryable into "query" variable, then create multiple predicates 

Example : Predicate<AdditionalInformation> OwnerPredicate = c => query.Any(t => c.Creator.Id == user.Id);)

Then I get results with :
query.Where(a => PredicateExtensions.OrAll(predicates)(a)).ToList();

Comment: Don't do `ToList().AsQueryable()`. This is *not* a real queryable, but LINQ to Objects implementation which runs in memory after retrieving all data. Remove `ToList()` and use just `IQueryable()`.

Comment: But the problem with it, is that my predicate system say that another operation is not finished

Comment: That's a different story. You have a concrete problem in your predicate system which needs to be resolved (you can ask a specific question providing a reproducible example), otherwise you have no choice and current question makes no sense.